# AEM/Livecycle - If total is over 100%, delete last entered value

Tags: javascript, aem, livecycle

hope you are safe and sound.

I have 5 numeric fields, formatted as "%". Display patter: num{9.8'%'}|num{99.8'%'}

Each field is limited to max. two characters with below script on change event:

```
if (xfa.event.newText > 99) {
xfa.event.change = "";
}
```

6th field is "Total", where sum is calculated for those 5 fields. Calculate event for the "Total" field:

this.rawValue = form1.Page1.Subform13.Subform14.Table4.Row1.Percent1.rawValue + ... form1.Page1.Subform13.Subform14.Table4.Row2.Percent5.rawValue;

Is it possible to go through all 5 fields and delete only the value from the field I'm currently in, if the "Total" is exceeding 100%? e.g.

"Percent1" = 55% + "Percent3" = 60%   -- delete 60% from Percent3

"Percent3" = 25% + "Percent5" = 70% + "Percent4" = 6%  -- delete 6% from Percent4

"Percent5" = 35% + "Percent2" = 90%   -- delete 90% from Percent2

like, any field combination and in any order?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make the script so it knows which field you are filling in, then calculate the rest of the fields.

If that is over 100, then delete the value in the field you are standing in.